Error while "parse error near do" while installing nvm
I installed nvm using the command in my mac.
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash 
After installation, there is a post install command where I have to run,
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm .
This fails with an error .nvm/nvm.sh:1097: parse error near do'`
Can someone help me resolve it?
I tried deleting contents of my .zshrc file, restarting my mac, uninstalling and re-installing the nvm but nothing worked.
This is what line 1097 looks like for ALIAS_PATH in "${NVM_ALIAS_DIR}/${ALIAS}"*; do

I realized that I had an alias on my .zshrc that was messing up with the nvm.sh file.
Removing the alias made it work.
